# Chrome 74: Deleting cookies takes very long time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm facing the issue that it takes approx. of 10 minutes to execute the `driver.delete_all_cookies()` after upgrading Chrome.

- With Chrome 73, no issues happen
- With Chrome 74, takes 10 minutes to finish this command

Especially, it only happens with `headless chrome`.

I also tried to upgrade the WebDriver to ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6, but the issue still persists

Is there any solutions for this one? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this exact same problem in headless mode with Chrome 74, ChromeDriver & Selenium (via Geb).  Once I added the following flag to ChromeDriver everything started working again:

`--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess`

I hope this helps you too.

Comment: I tried to apply these flags and it worked like a charm! Thank you much!

Comment: This method seems work with Chrome 74 & Driver 74. However, I faced another issue, sometimes session is expired unexpectedly when the test is running and I am disconnected to Login screen of my web, I don't know the reason why...

Answer (score 3):

There is **Browser Cleaning Data Issue** in **Chrome Browser v74**. It takes too long  to reset and clear cache data and  it never stops and  the  blue circle  going around and around and never stop. Please try to disable all the unusual extensions if there.

I am not sure if its already logged. But i logged **Issue - 960325**. Would keep you updated if i hear something on this.

**Note -** You would face this issue if you delete cookies manually or by scripts irrespective of browser mode. For some people it got resolved automatically.

Comment: Thank you! Looking forward to your response soon!

Comment: @Nhat Linh Nguyen, chromium team had been waiting for my feedback on the ticket and as now issue is no more re-producible in my case. But many other feedback has been given to chromium team. But seems like till now they could not get logs for debugging so still no resolution for those who facing it. Will see if hear more something on this.